# Conflict in wlan0 management on ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I am trying to enable wlan0 through systemctl on ArchLinux. When I do that I get the message that the device is already up. So I do

`sudo ip link set wlan0 down`

I can than successfully run `sudo systemctl start "netctl@wlan0\\x2dwifi.service"`

How can I set the default state `wlan0` on down so that `systemctl` can take over management of `wlan0`?

Comment: You shouldn't combine manual and automatic methods of management; as long as `netctl` is the *only* network service enabled, it should handle the device for you...

Comment: I realize that but now I don't know how to disable manual. Any advise?

Comment: Make sure it is the only networking service enabled, and reboot: it should all be good.

Comment: Sorry, n00b on archlinux, how do I do that?

Comment: Read the wiki entry on wireless networking...

Comment: I did but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. I disabled manual wifi and found out that the profile that is created by `wifi-menu -o` contains a dash. As a result of the dash `netctl` is unable to load the profile. Renaming the profile located in `/etc/netctl/` to something without the dash resolved the issue.